# Tensorflow mean square error calculation differers from sklearn

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to calculate `mse` using tensorflow and compare the result with `sklearn.metrics.mean_squared_error` method.

```
def mse(y,y_hat):
    return tf.reduce_mean(tf.squared_difference(y, y_hat)).eval()

compute_mse = lambda vector1, vector2: mse(vector1,vector2)
```

My test loop

```
for n in [1,5,10,10**3]:

    elems = [np.arange(n),np.arange(n,0,-1), np.zeros(n),
             np.ones(n),np.random.random(n),np.random.randint(100,size=n)]

    for el in elems:
        for el_2 in elems:
            true_mse = np.array(mean_squared_error(el,el_2))
            my_mse = compute_mse(el,el_2)
            if not np.allclose(true_mse,my_mse):
                print('Wrong result:')

print("All tests passed")
```

But my tf function always return either 0 or 1.
Could you please point me where I'm wrong.

**UPD**

Thanks to @apnorton for pointing on issue with types.

```
def mse(y,y_hat):
    y_ = tf.Variable(y, tf.float64)
    y_hat_ = tf.Variable(y_hat, tf.float64)
    return tf.reduce_mean(tf.squared_difference(y_, y_hat_).eval()
```

Answer (score 3):

If you print all the outputs of your tf function, you'll see it doesn't return only 1s and 0s, but it *does* only return integers.  This is because the values of `elems` are all of type `numpy.int32`.  The `sklearn` function appears to cast these as floats when doing the mean step, while the Tensor Flow approach does not.

To see a fixed variant, consider changing the `compute_mse` line to:

```
my_mse = compute_mse(el.astype(float),el_2.astype(float))
```

---

**Edit:** In response to the question in the comments, I'd avoid creating a variable only for the purpose of a cast.  Instead, I'd recommend using the [`tf.to_float`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/to_float) method:

```
def mse(y,y_hat):
    return tf.reduce_mean(tf.squared_difference(tf.to_float(y), tf.to_float(y_hat))).eval()
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked. I have updated the question. Can you check whether it is a proper approach for typecasting when using tensorflow?